# A word that expresses that something is correlated with X and negatively correlated with its opposite

Tags: word-request

I can't think of any concise way of saying this. When you say A happens progressively as you do X, it doesn't mean that the opposite of A happens when you do the opposite of X. Is there a way to say this properly?

For example:

> The health bar of the enemy progressively shrink as you shoot the
>   enemy, and progressively replenishes itself when he gets healed my a
>   teammate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of "[direct correlation](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/direct+correlation)":

> **direct correlation** = a correlation in which large values of one variable are associated with large values of the other and small with small; the correlation coefficient is between 0 and +1

From [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/correlation):

> Researchers have found a **direct correlation** between smoking and lung cancer.

---

In your example:

> The health bar of the enemy is **directly correlated** with taking hits (shrinking) and with healing (replenishing).